# Is there an alternative to System.Windows.ResourceKey to use in MonoTouch?

Tags: c#, iphone, dll, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I need to use ResourceKey for the key in my Dictionary and was wondering if there was a similar class I could use in MonoTouch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to use a string.

If you need to use other things as a key (like a System.Type in WPF), then create your own class to handle this.  I'm not sure if this work is worth it, however.